# Vertically moving figure in minipage

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, minipage

I want to put plot 5 figures in a specific way like this:
[image]

For this I use the following code in LaTeX:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
        \vspace*{-2cm}
        \centering
        \subfloat[Figure 1]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figure1.png}}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \subfloat[Figure 2]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figure2.png}}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \subfloat[Figure 3]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figure3.png}}
    \end{minipage}\par\medskip
    \hspace{4.7cm}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \subfloat[Figure 4]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figure4.png}}
    \end{minipage} 
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \subfloat[Figure 5]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figure5.png}}
    \end{minipage} \par\medskip
\end{figure}
```

However, now the figures end up like this:
[image]

I'm not sure what I should do to get the minipages aligned the way I want them. Do any of you maybe have some suggestions?

Thanks in advance!
Michelle

Comment: You might want to have a look at the `adjustbox` package

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Where are the images?

Comment: Sorry something went wrong. I think you can see the images now?

Answer (score 3):

Here's solution that places the first subfigure in a `minipage` of `0.3\linewidth` and places the next four subfigures in a `minipage` of width `0.65\linewidth`, leaving `0.05\linewidth` of horizontal whitespace between the graphs. The calculations are done with an eye to ensuring that all 5 subfigure graphs are equally wide.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty,skip=0.25\baselineskip}
\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
\subfloat[Subfigure 1]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure1}}%
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{.05\linewidth}%
\begin{minipage}{.65\linewidth}
%% 0.461 = 0.3/0.65
\subfloat[Subfigure 2]{\includegraphics[width=0.461\linewidth]{figure2}}%
\hspace{\fill} 
\subfloat[Subfigure 3]{\includegraphics[width=0.461\linewidth]{figure3}}

\medskip
\subfloat[Subfigure 4]{\includegraphics[width=0.461\linewidth]{figure4}}%
\hspace{\fill}
\subfloat[Subfigure 5]{\includegraphics[width=0.461\linewidth]{figure5}}
\end{minipage}
\caption{A figure with 5 subfigures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A tabular environment could help organize the figures. The `nicematrix` package provides the `\Block` command to create multi-row / column cells. In this case, `\Block {2-1} {...}`  creates a cell 2 rows high x 1 column width, with its content centered inside.

The `cell-space-limits` directive allows cells to be expanded vertically if desired.

The final code is very simple and it is easy to change the geometry of the layout.

[image: d]

[image: e]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[position=bottom]{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{nicematrix} % added <<<<

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty} 
        \caption{Default spacing}
        
    \begin{NiceTabular}{ccc} 
        
    \Block{2-1}{\subfloat[Figure 1]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}}}
            &\subfloat[Figure 2]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}}&\subfloat[Figure 3]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}} \\ 
            &\subfloat[Figure 4]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}}&\subfloat[Figure 5]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}} \\ 
            
    \end{NiceTabular}   

\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty} 
    \caption{Expanding the cells}
    
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{20pt} %columns separation
    
    \begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[cell-space-limits=6pt] % expand the cells vertically
        
        \Block{2-1}{\subfloat[Figure 1]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}}}
        &\subfloat[Figure 2]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}}&\subfloat[Figure 3]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}} \\ 
        &\subfloat[Figure 4]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}}&\subfloat[Figure 5]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}} \\ 
        
    \end{NiceTabular}   
    
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A small variation of your MWE which reproduce showed image: images are paired in `minipages`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \captionsetup{skip=0.5ex}
\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    \caption*{Figure 1}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
        \caption*{Figure 2}
        
    \bigskip
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    \caption*{Figure 4}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    \caption*{Figure 3}
    
    \bigskip
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    \caption*{Figure 5}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]